# Why "uninstall" instead of "disable" in system app?

Tags: android

I'm trying to install one of my apps as system app. It does everything correctly except the fact that when you try to uninstall it instead of showing "disable" as other stock apps lets you uninstall the app.

After uninstalling the app from there, it is impossible to install the app again pushing it to /system/priv-app.

To install the app I've pushed it to /system/priv-app after remounting. I've tried to chmod 644 it or not, nothing changes.

Any idea of the reason why?

Comment: not sure, but a sys-app need to be signed with some official release keys or special keys (not self signed)

Comment: I am not sure (just an idea), but check, if your app is still in applications list. If you have more than one user, you should do "uninstall for all users".

Comment: it is in application list. Yazan, that was my worry. Though services installed this way are installed in the right way. Uhm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the app needs to be signed. I thought it should be signed with the ROM's keys... but no, it's not needed at all. You can use your own key and it works.